# How to calculate the power of a DC shunt generator?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-motor, generator, induction-motor, power-generation

How much power a DC shunt generator can generate if it was coupled with this induction motor:

Induction motor:

- 3-phase / 400v / 50Hz / 600w / 1250RPM

DC generator:

- Excitation voltage: 0-220VDC
- Excitation current: 0.14A
- Max. output voltage: 220VDC
- Max. Output power: 600W
- Max. rotate speed: 3000rpm

Comment: Less than 600 watts.

Comment: I did some calculations and I end up with 300W at 1500RPM, can I assume that
//////
P_gen = (V_field * I_gen) * (N / N_base)
//////
 N / N_base becomes 1500 / 3000 = 0.5
//////
P_gen_1500 = 600W * 0.5 = 300W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltage output of DC generator depends on speed and magnetic flux. In the specified case of shunt generator, there are some more constraints:

1. Speed: Voltage will be linear dependant to speed, but below some speed (critical speed,) the residual magnetic flux will be not able to build up voltage. If 1250 RPM is below this limit, voltage output will be null, but if it is higher a reduction of 1250/3000 RPM should apply.
2. Flux: It depends of field current, but the ferritic magnetic path can work in saturation, it is not linear. Field current is proportional to generator output voltage, so an additional reduction will be apply because of this. The output voltage will build up at field resistance line and voltage open circuit characteristics (OCC) of generator intersecction point. If field resistance line is above OCC curve, no voltage output will build up.

See graphics from https://electricalbaba.com/voltage-build-up-in-dc-shunt-generator/

[image]

Comment: The color choices in that graph have room for improvement.